# Quarkus - Open a database connection at runtime

Tags: java, quarkus, graalvm-native-image

Is it possible to open a database connection at runtime using quarkus jdbc drivers? If so how would I go about doing it. Also would the mechanism work with native images?

Basically I wish to get a connection object to the database so I can run a custom query.

Answer (score 0):

You can override some properties at runtime. You can view them here:

[quarkus datasources](https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource#configuration-reference)

Answer (score 0):

runtime sounds confusing. You can override BEFORE starting app. Imagine the case, you have `url_XXX` and `url_YYY`.
You can start app with

```
-Dquarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=url_XXX
```

and get datasource with connection to url_XXX. There is no option to get connection to `url_YYY` in runtime. You'll have to restart app with

```
-Dquarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=url_YYY
```

in order to connect to different DB.

Another option would be to use named datasources, but still you have define them at build time and provide url BEFORE starting app.

```
-Dquarkus.datasource.YYY.jdbc.url=url_YYY -Dquarkus.datasource.XXX.jdbc.url=url_XXX
```

Quarkus names it "runtime", but actually it's "pre-runtime"